# Discount Coupon issue In x-cart

Tags: php, x-cart

as the structure of x-cart, orderid is created on the base of providers. there are 3 scenarios.:

1. **If a customer is purchasing 2 different items from one provider, then orderid will be one and itemid will be 2.**
2. **If a customer is purchasing 2 same item from one provider, both orderid and itemid will be 1 and amount field of itemid will be counted as 2.**
3. **when customer is purchasing 2 items from 2 different providers then both orderid and itemid will be different.**

I stuck on the 3rd scenario. there are 2 scopes of discount coupons, either you can give it as `percentage` or as `flat discount`.

- when I am trying to give flat discount it is counting for both products, let say **I am giving a 200RS discount on the product which has 500+ RS price.**

Now the issue is there is a loop which is counting discount on products. so when there will be 2 providers discount will be counted on both products because there will be 2 orderids.

when I am trying to break a loop when there is a discount. the site is crashing. there is no way to stop the loop. because if we are stopping a loop, so the data which is needed to order array will be not there and the script will be crash. did anyone face same issue? or do anyone have any solution regarding this?

what I need is discount should be counted on cart subtotal, not on products. have tried too many things but haven't found any solution yet. if you guys have any idea about it, please tell me.

thank you.

Comment: which X-Cart version do you use ?

Comment: @IldarAmankulov it's 4.7

Comment: Coupons are provider based in X-Cart platinum edition. They have to be applied to the provider's products only,don't they? https://demo.x-cart.com/demo_platinum/provider/coupons.php

Comment: yes that is the actual problem. when there will be 2 product from 2 different providers. so discont will be counted for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One custom solution for the problem 
"what I need is discount should be counted on cart subtotal, not on products." may be auxiliary hidden coupons.

- A new 'main_coupon' flag should be added to xcart_discount_coupons table
- A customer will use an one 'main' coupon total_discount=$10
- X-Cart will use 2 or more 'child' coupons in the calculation. For example couponA=$5 and couponB=$5

This is a piece of example code for func_calculate_discounts function

```
    //$discount_coupon_data = func_query_first("SELECT * FROM $sql_tbl[discount_coupons] WHERE coupon='" . addslashes($discount_coupon) . "' $provider_condition");
    //find related child coupons instead of main coupon             
    $discount_coupon_data = MultiCoupon::getChildCouponByMainCouponCode($discount_coupon, $provider_condition);
```

where MultiCoupon::getChildCouponByMainCouponCode is something like

```
class MultiCoupon {
    public static function getChildCouponByMainCouponCode($main_coupon_code, $provider_condition) {
        global $sql_tbl;

        $child_discount_coupon_data = func_query_first("SELECT child_coupons.* FROM $sql_tbl[discount_coupons] as child_coupons INNER JOIN $sql_tbl[discount_coupons_links] as main_coupons ON child_coupons.main_code = main_coupons.code AND main_coupons.code='" . addslashes($main_coupon_code) . "' $provider_condition");
        return $child_discount_coupon_data;
    }
}
```

I.E. you should substitute coupon data based on one coupon code to multiple coupons based on providers.

Comment: can you please explain it in details? I didn't get what you want to say. sorry.

Comment: so do i have to create new table as `discount_coupons_links`?

Comment: Yes, if you choose this solution. There may be other ways.

Comment: still, i didn't get how will it work? still, the discount will be counted for both products.

Comment: Internally, there will be 2 coupons, one per each item

Comment: Will it substracted for each product from main coupon itself??

Comment: I suppose, that no. The main coupon works as a link to the child coupons.

Comment: so it means admin have to create 2 coupons every time?